# Configure Jetty password on websocket client tutorial

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty

I'm following a [tutorial](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-websocket-client-api.html#_the_websocketclient) to get a web socket client working in Java using Eclipse but I keep running into this message whenever I try to run the code the program:

*Usage - java org.eclipse.jetty.security.Password []*

*If the password is ?, the user will be prompted for the password*

This is the code for the client

```
public class SimpleEchoClient
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String destUri = "ws://echo.websocket.org";
        if (args.length > 0)
        {
            destUri = args[0];
        }

        WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient();
        SimpleEchoSocket socket = new SimpleEchoSocket();
        try
        {
            client.start();

            URI echoUri = new URI(destUri);
            ClientUpgradeRequest request = new ClientUpgradeRequest();
            client.connect(socket,echoUri,request);
            System.out.printf("Connecting to : %s%n",echoUri);

            // wait for closed socket connection.
            socket.awaitClose(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                client.stop();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code for the websocket connection

```
@WebSocket(maxTextMessageSize = 64 * 1024)
public class SimpleEchoSocket
{
    private final CountDownLatch closeLatch;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Session session;

    public SimpleEchoSocket()
    {
        this.closeLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    }

    public boolean awaitClose(int duration, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException
    {
        return this.closeLatch.await(duration,unit);
    }

    @OnWebSocketClose
    public void onClose(int statusCode, String reason)
    {
        System.out.printf("Connection closed: %d - %s%n",statusCode,reason);
        this.session = null;
        this.closeLatch.countDown(); // trigger latch
    }

    @OnWebSocketConnect
    public void onConnect(Session session)
    {
        System.out.printf("Got connect: %s%n",session);
        this.session = session;
        try
        {
            Future<Void> fut;
            fut = session.getRemote().sendStringByFuture("Hello");
            fut.get(2,TimeUnit.SECONDS); // wait for send to complete.

            fut = session.getRemote().sendStringByFuture("Thanks for the conversation.");
            fut.get(2,TimeUnit.SECONDS); // wait for send to complete.

            session.close(StatusCode.NORMAL,"I'm done");
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @OnWebSocketMessage
    public void onMessage(String msg)
    {
        System.out.printf("Got msg: %s%n",msg);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

That tutorial and the code samples have no password requirements.

The message you are getting is because you are running the `org.eclipse.jetty.security.Password` class directly, and not your websocket client code.

Change how you run your compiled project to run the correct class (from the looks of it, that would be your class `SimpleEchoClient`, but you don't show your package namespace so that classname could be incomplete)